# How to know C++ derived class's base class?

Tags: c++

Assume I have a base class `A`, and two abstract class `B` and `C`, and their derived class `D` and `E`.

How can I distinguish `D` and `E`'s last layer class? (`D`'s last layer class is `B`, `E` is `C`)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() { return 1; } };
class ClassB : public ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() override =0; };
class ClassC : public ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() override =0; };

class D : public ClassB { public: virtual int testFunc() override {return 2;} };
class E : public ClassC { public: virtual int testFunc() override {return 3;} };

int main() {
  ClassA * d = new D();
  ClassA * e = new E(); // !!! how can i know e's last layer class C by pointer e?????
  if (somemethod(*e) == somemethod(ClassC)) {  // somemethod is what i want
     // do something
   } else {
     // do something
   }
 }
```

I know `typeid` may help on this, but the code output should be `D` and `E`, how can I know their last layer class?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but you can try to `dynamic_cast` the `A*` pointer into `B*` or `C*`.

Comment: @interjay i just need to judge their class type, my purpose is: ```if (somemethod(*e) == somemethod(ClassC)) .....```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/130940).  If you're doing polymorphism correctly, it shouldn't matter what the "last layer" is.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this information? (What you describe as your purpose doesn't make much sense - types are not first-class values in C++. Instead of showing what you want to write, describe what you want to accomplish.)

Comment: That's the job of the c++ runtime dispatcher to inspect what the most derived type is with the help of typeid Comparison:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid or dynamic_cast conversion:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast also see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzJL-8WbpuU

Comment: interjay's proposal seems to do the job: `if (auto* c = dynamic_cast<ClassC*>(e))`.

Comment: If you need to know that this means that you are using polymorphism in wrong way. Whole point of OOP is that you do not have to know detail of used object. If you need to do type checking this usually means that abstractions (interfaces) are not correctly designed.

Comment: If the user of an instance has to know which type of instance is provided, the design is fully broken! It is the target of runtime polymorphism to hide such implementation details from the interface/user at all. If you really need it, you are using the wrong idea/implementation.

Comment: Some language (Java or Python) provide *introspection*, that is a way to find at run time the available methods, properties or base classes of an object. C++ does not. For that reason, when using C++ you should never have to *guess* properties or bases, and if you really need, you have to manage explicit properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already in the comments, you can use `dynamic_cast` as a replacement of `somemethod` in your code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() { return 1; } };
class ClassB : public ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() override =0; };
class ClassC : public ClassA { public: virtual int testFunc() override =0; };

class D : public ClassB { public: virtual int testFunc() override {return 2;} };
class E : public ClassC { public: virtual int testFunc() override {return 3;} };

int main() {
  //ClassA * d = new D();
  ClassA * e = new E();
  if ( dynamic_cast<ClassC*>(e) ) {
     std::cout << "classC is among (e) parents";
   } else {
     std::cout << "classC is not a parent of (e)";
   }
 }
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TYdPzeMcT